# Копировать список

Tags: python, list

Как скопировать список друг за другом 10 раз?

Допустим `list = [1,2,3]`, и 3 раза копий - тогда list = `[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python интересный язык, можно сделать так:

```
l = [1,2,3]*3
```

Comment: Вот как раз-таки "так" лучше не делать. Что не так: 1. Переменная названа также как и built-in функция `list`; 2. Между оператором необходимо поставить пробелы. Работать оно и так будет, но запись является некорректной.

Comment: @AlTheOne Хотя переменную так назвал автор вопроса, но поправлять такое в ответах, конечно, надо. А так то запись корректная, но чреватая побочными эффектами из-за названия переменной.

Comment: @AlTheOne согласен

Comment: @CrazyElf Думаю начинающему в Python необходимо все недочёты подсветить. Понимаю, что никто никому ничем не обязан, но можно и ответственнее подойти к ответу. Я постарался со своей стороны сделать это.

Comment: @Komdosh Благодарю!